# GWT compiled code optimization

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction

My compiled js gets bigger and bigger these days. When I took a look at the GWT output cache.html, I was surprised seeing the first hundreds of lines in the form:

```
function it(){}
function ht(){}
function tt(){}
function It(){}
function Gt(){}
function Lt(){}
...
```

And then hundreds of

```
function Qy(b){this.b=b}
function QR(b){this.b=b}
function iR(b){this.b=b}
function tR(b){this.b=b}
function GM(b){this.b=b}
...
```

Is this something that can be easily optimized, or if I am missing some switches on the compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, most (if not all) of these functions are *constructors*; their `.prototype` will be assigned later; so there's no way to *merge* them together.

Note that the compiler groups them together so that GZip produces smaller compressed files, see http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2009/08/on-reducing-size-of-compressed.html

The GWT team is also continuously working on optimizing the generated JS code, so always stick to the latest GWT version and you'll see improvements coming (for instance, there's [work in progress](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10778) for using the Closure Compiler to further optimize the generated JS, in addition to changing the way Java is transformed to JS, e.g. [r10441](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10441), [r10480](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10480), [r10825](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10825), etc.)